# What is the problem with the `#import` directive mentioned below?

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, gcc

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/cpp/Obsolete-once_002donly-headers.html) you'll find the following statement:

> `#import` is not a well designed feature. It requires the users of a
>   header file to know that it should only be included once.

What is the problem with this?

Comment: It is a biased article, no surprise given the source.  `#import` was designed for NeXTSTEP ages ago and was never intended to be portable beyond Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article states the problem pretty exactly: If you write a header with the intention that it's been used with #import (aka without any include guards/etc), then you *expect* the user of that header file to use #import or other means to make sure that the file is only included once. If the user doesn't know that, or if the header is used with a compiler that doesn't support #import (or does something else with that command), then your header will not work properly. And, especially in big projects with many people working on it, there's a good chance that someday someone might accidantally #include that header instead, or that the project gets ported to a different compiler some time in the future.